# Regex to find string between to special character

Tags: regex

I have string like this

```
abc{[data1]}efg{[data2]}
```

I need a regex that returns `data1` and `data2`.

I tried `Regex(@"{[\w*]}")` but no hope.

Comment: Not sure, what programming language you are using, but `/\[([a-z]*[1-9]*)\]/g` will do the trick. I would recommend using [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) for testing regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the special regex characters, otherwise `[\w*]` is treated as *1 word character or an asterisk*:

```
@"\{\[\w*\]}"
  ^ ^    ^
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%7B%5C%5B%5Cw*%5C%5D%7D&i=abc%7B%5Bdata1%5D%7Defg%7B%5Bdata2%5D%7D)

Comment: I guess you are using C#, right? Then, you can actually use [`@"{\[\w*]}"`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%7b%5c%5b%5cw*%5d%7d&i=abc%7b%5bdata1%5d%7defg%7b%5bdata2%5d%7d), since C# regex engine is smart enough to understand that the `{`, `}` and `]` are to be matched literally.